# Attempting to solve mutating table issue with compound trigger

Tags: oracle

I am attempting to follow the instructions at [Mutating Table Compound Trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CHDFEBFJ) to update a parent table based on the id of a child table and avoid a mutating table error.

I need to obtain the parent id (BLATranscriptId) of the current record in the BLATChildren table and then **after** the update of the child record completes, I need to extract the current count that matches my criteria and perform an update on the parent table BLATranscript.

**THIS ERROR HAS BEEN SOLVED** - I'm getting an error that my bind variable "transcriptID" is bad in the "AFTER EACH ROW" portion of my code.  I've verify that the BLATChildren.BLATranscriptId exists and is spelled correctly. **Solution** was to change AFTER EACH ROW to AFTER STATEMENT.

**NEW ISSUE** - Trigger is updating every record in the parent table, not just the matching parent record.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER transcript_after_update
FOR UPDATE of enrollmentStatus,completionDate on blatChildren
COMPOUND TRIGGER
         transcriptID number:=0;
BEFORE EACH ROW IS 
BEGIN
       transcriptID := :new.blaTranscriptid;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;       
AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    update BLATranscript SET (enrollmentStatus, completionDate) = (select 'C',sysdate from dual)
    where id in (select blat.id from BLATranscript blat 
    inner join BlendedActivity bla on blat.blendedactivityid=bla.id
    where blat.id=transcriptID and minCompletion<=(
    select count(countForCompletion) as total from blatChildren blac
    inner join BlendedActivityMembership bam on blac.childActivityId=bam.childActivityId
    where completionDate>=sysdate-acceptPrevWork
    and blat.id=transcriptID
    and blac.enrollmentStatus='C'));
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;   
/
```

Comment: You can't reference the table on which the trigger is defined in any row-level portion of the trigger.  You'd need to do that in a statement-level portion of the trigger.  You almost certainly want your local variable to be a collection, rather than a scalar, and you want the statement-level portion of your trigger to iterate over the elements of the collection.  Your reference to the local variable in the statement-level portion of your trigger would not be preceded with a colon.  Just use `transcriptID` rather than `:transcriptID` (or whatever you name your collection).

Comment: @sstan - Thank you.  That solved the BIND variable issue, however now it's giving me an issue regarding the mutating table problem I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @JustinCave - Thank you.  I assume by collection you are thinking something closer to what the documentation used like a temporary table?  I've got a mental block though because to me that appears as though it would update every record in the parent table every time a child record is updated.  I'm obviously not understanding this very well.

Comment: The documentation is using a collection (specifically a nested table) not a temporary table.  But yes, that's what I'm suggesting you follow.  Most likely, you want the row-level portion of your trigger to add the `:new.transactionID` to the collection and then you want to iterate over the elements of the collection (or use the collection in a join) in the `after statement` portion of your trigger to determine which row(s) to update.

Comment: @JustinCave - Thanks.  I'll give that a try and come back and give an update after I've attempted following the example exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need for each row part to collect `:new.blaTranscriptid` int PL/SQL table
and after statement part that will perform update using this PL/SQL table.
Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER transcript_after_update
FOR UPDATE of enrollmentStatus,completionDate on blatChildren
COMPOUND TRIGGER
    TYPE transcriptIDs_t  IS TABLE OF blatChildren.blaTranscriptid%TYPE;
    transcriptID transcriptIDs_t := transcriptIDs_t();
BEFORE EACH ROW IS 
BEGIN
    transcriptID.extend;
       transcriptID(transcriptID.count) := :new.blaTranscriptid;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;       
AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..transcriptID.COUNT
  LOOP
    update BLATranscript SET (enrollmentStatus, completionDate) = (select 'C',sysdate from dual)
    where id in (select blat.id from BLATranscript blat 
    inner join BlendedActivity bla on blat.blendedactivityid=bla.id
    where blat.id = transcriptID(i) and minCompletion<=(
    select count(countForCompletion) as total from blatChildren blac
    inner join BlendedActivityMembership bam on blac.childActivityId=bam.childActivityId
    where completionDate>=sysdate-acceptPrevWork
    and blat.id=transcriptID(i)
    and blac.enrollmentStatus='C'));
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;   
/
```

Comment: Are you saying to use a PL/SQL table instead of bind variable?

Comment: I posted trigger example (but I don't have Oracle nearby, so some typos may exists). Variable of type number is not something you need because it can store only 1 value so if outer UPDATE statement will update several rows, only one latest value will be used in triggers UPDATE statement.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  You've done some stuff in your EACH ROW section I'm not familiar with so it will take me a little research to understand it all.  Thank you so much.  I'll get back after I've done some more research and tried this out.

Comment: Anyway, my main point that you need to use AFTER STATEMENT block instead of AFTER EACH ROW to query blatChildren, otherwise you'll get Mutating table error.

Comment: "Before each row" section just contain adding blatranscriptid values into PL/SQL table

Comment: Okay, I get it.  Sorry, I've never used Collections in Oracle before so I wasn't familiar with the syntax.  I thought you were actually trying to count the records but I see you are just using it like an "array" position and extend just adds to the length.  Thanks for being patient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90474/discussion-between-trebor-and-anton-zaviriukhin).